# Xcode Build failed If I add upload debug symbols to sentry script

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-sentry

Unable to build the app If I add the Upload Debug Symbols to sentry. Also in Xcode it showing

```
Continuing in background
Failed to display Xcode notification


 export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties
    ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli upload-dsym
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case `SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN` env variable was missing in the setup.

You can create token in Sentry Settings:
https://[your org slug].sentry.io/settings/auth-tokens/

[Sentry docs on Auth Tokens](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/auth-tokens/)